# Django server access

Tags: django, phpmyadmin, laragon

Is it possible to view your database schema using the django server like one does using phpmyadmin or any other tool to view what is in your database. I have used laragon with laravel was wondering if there is something similar to it in django.

Comment: Why don't you use phpmyadmin?

Comment: How do you do that in Django?

Comment: You don't, you do it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: i will look on how to do that. I use the default django server, should i change?

Comment: do you mean something like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/ ?